# Distinguishing partition format types

Tags: partitioning, format, fat32, exfat

How can I tell whether a partition is formatted with FAT32 or exFAT?

Answer (score 2):

`fdisk` can list the partition types. On my system I get:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4b66b5d5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *       81920    30801919    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        30801920   194643539    81920810    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       194643601   976773119   391064759+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       194643603   198836504     2096451    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda6       342951936   960387071   308717568   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       198840320   342949887    72054784   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       960389120   976773119     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```